# How to find the variable in javascript which gives the positions of the competitors on the site sapsailing?

Tags: education

As part of my studies, I’m looking for a way to find the variable in the javascript representing the positions of competitors on this site to retrieve the data.

https://www.sapsailing.com/gwt/Home.html#/regatta/races/:eventId=2d42185c-c914-4042-814f-14108218b3a3&regattaId=HWCS%202020%20Round%201%20-%20RS:X%20Men

Comment: you mean, you want to scrape certain data? the source code is obfuscated, but you can likely use python + selenium + headless chrome = https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python

Answer (score 1):

The data is loaded from an [RPC endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). Here's an example for the page you linked.

```
curl 'https://www.sapsailing.com/gwt/service/dispatch/leaderboard/HWCS_2020_Round_1___RS_X_Men' \
-H 'Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8' \
-H 'X-GWT-Permutation: ED484971D331FCA3E1C2F5147D82354E' \
--data '7|0|15|https://www.sapsailing.com/gwt/com.sap.sailing.gwt.home.Home/|4205A5A89AAFD558382546D34E70232D|com.sap.sse.gwt.dispatch.client.transport.gwtrpc.DispatchRPC|execute|com.sap.sse.gwt.dispatch.client.transport.gwtrpc.RequestWrapper/2132896796|com.sap.sse.gwt.dispatch.client.system.batching.BatchAction/3379882599|java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|com.sap.sailing.gwt.home.communication.event.GetRegattaWithProgressAction/909705156|java.util.UUID/82115148|2d42185c-c914-4042-814f-14108218b3a3|HWCS 2020 Round 1 - RS:X Men|com.sap.sailing.gwt.home.communication.event.GetLiveRacesForRegattaAction/1382191286|com.sap.sailing.gwt.home.communication.event.GetFinishedRacesAction/3175709897|en|java.util.Date/3385151746|1|2|3|4|1|5|5|6|7|3|8|9|10|11|12|-5|11|13|-5|11|14|15|W8ehPFq|'
```